# Multiple users on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, virtualization, virtual-machine

Is it possible to have multiple users to manage an Amazon EC2 environment? I want to give access to several additional people to create machines on my existing billing account.

Answer (score 6):

Amazon just announced AWS Identity and Access Management - http://aws.amazon.com/iam/

As of right now, it's in 'preview' mode, but this will allow you to have multiple AWS management accounts.

Comment: this is the correct answer. (I don't think it's in preview mode anymore though as I have set up users on our EC2, including users with read-only access)

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago Amazon [announced Consolidated Billing](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/02/09/announcing-consolidated-billing-for-aws-accounts/). I never used it, but I think that is what you're looking for:

> Consolidated Billing enables you to see a combined view of AWS costs incurred by all accounts in your department or company, as well as obtain a detailed cost report for each individual AWS account associated with your paying account. Consolidated Billing may also lower your overall costs since the rolled up usage across all of your accounts could help you reach lower-priced volume tiers more quickly.

- [Consolidated Billing Guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSConsolidatedBilling/1.0/AWSConsolidatedBillingGuide.html)

Comment: hmm. I posted the same link just a second ago and didn't see your post. I wonder if something is broken with SO?

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely possible using IAM service of AWS. With the help of IAM you can create users and give them specific permissions on various services of amazon.

Answer (score -1):

You can try http://LabSlice.com. It's primarily for Virtual Lab Management (ie. playground environments), but may suit your needs.

Comment: Please mention your affiliation with a web site or product when you recommend your own stuff.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am affiliated with the above mentioned site. It's linked off my profile, so I wasn't trying to be underhanded ;-).

Comment: No, I understand you weren't trying anything shady.  It's just a relatively new policy on SO to disclose your affiliation on every post where you mention your own product or company.

Comment: Its a broken link. And please don't do advertisements.